# ManyToMany, minimum set of keys from KeyTable1 that match selected items from KeyTable2? (I need classes w,x,y,z, what mimimum teachers satisfy that)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, many-to-many

In a many to many relationship, I'm trying to solve a problem where I need to find the smallest set of items from the first table that provide coverage for an arbitrary set of selected items from the second table.

For example, imagine:
Teacher (TeacherID)
Class (ClassID)
TeachClassXref (TeacherID, ClassID)

If a student needs to study classes: 34,45,53,56,44,77,23,654,667

How would one determine the smallest set of TeacherID's that would teach those classes?

(Also to be determined: in the case where complete coverage cannot be achieved, the outlier classes with no common teacher.)

---

Or using terminology from a different domain (but exact same table structure):

Activities & Roles:  if I need to perform Activities 1,3,6,7,9,33,45, what Role or set of Roles do I need to belong to?

(I'm sure there has to be a name for this problem but my google-fu is failing me.)

Comment: do we need to consider the teachers already commited

Comment: Basically, these 3 tables describe which teachers teach which classes; each class has multiple teachers, each teacher teaches multiple classes).  Then, a student needs some set of <n> classes, and needs to know which single teacher, or which smallest set of teachers, teach ALL of those classes.

Comment: Consider a scenario A teacher is already occupied with a set of class. In which table is used to keep this info

Comment: Actual class schedules are outside the scope - teachers & classes is just an example application of this problem, my actual scenario is Activities & Roles:  if I need to perform Activities 1,3,6,7,9,33,45, what role or set of roles do I need to be assigned?

Comment: Can you provide some test data with expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
SELECT
ClassID
into #RequiredClass
from CLass
where ClassID in (34,45,53,56,44,77,23,654,667)


create table #BestTeacher (TeacherID int)

while 1 = 1
begin

insert  #BestTeacher
SELECT top 1
  Teacher.TeacherID
FROM
  Teacher
  INNER JOIN TeacherClass
          ON Teacher.TeacherID = TeacherClass.TeacherID
  INNER JOIN #RequiredClass as Class
          ON TeacherClass.ClassID = Class.ClassID 
GROUP BY
  Teacher.TeacherID
  ,Teacher.TeacherName
order by count(Teacher.TeacherID) desc


delete #RequiredClass
where ClassID in (

 SELECT
#RequiredClass.ClassID
from #RequiredClass 
inner join 
  Teacher
  INNER JOIN TeacherClass
          ON Teacher.TeacherID = TeacherClass.TeacherID
  INNER JOIN Class
          ON TeacherClass.ClassID = Class.ClassID
on #RequiredClass.ClassID = Class.ClassID
inner join #BestTeacher
on #BestTeacher.TeacherID = Teacher.TeacherID)

   if @@rowcount = 0 break
end


select * from #BestTeacher
drop table #BestTeacher
drop table #RequiredClass
```

Comment: Interesting....I will have to think about this a bit more but it looks workable at first glance.